# in jquery calendar I want to restrict all future dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying code like

```
$('#paymentDate').datepicker({
    format: 'd/m/yyyy',
    maxDate: 0
});
```

But its not showing me results after click on text box. It is allow me to select all dates.

Comment: Try `maxDate: new Date()`

Comment: I tried this thing also but not working..

Comment: try this one http://jqueryasp.net/disable-future-dates-jquery-ui-datepicker-asp-net/

Comment: This is one solution I have found.function function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var today = curr_date + "/" + (curr_month + 1) + "/" + curr_year;
    if ($('#payDate').val() > today) {
        $('#payDate').val(today);
    }
}     Which is working perfectly.

Comment: which datepicker are you using ?if it is solved then post it as answer